# How to apply Page Flip in Windows Phone 7 in news based Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
Mainpage.xaml.cs code

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{ string f;
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();



WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);


webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/mobileservice.aspx?service=topstories"));

}

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewsItem>>(e.Result);




foreach (var item in rootObject)
{


// Console.WriteLine(item.news_id + "new_id");
f += '|'+item.news_id;
//f ='|' + item.news_id;




}

lstEmployee.ItemsSource = rootObject;
}




private void lstEmployee_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
int selindex = lstEmployee.SelectedIndex;

//ListBox sourceList = sender as ListBox;
//ListBox.se



(Application.Current as App).selectedNewsItem = lstEmployee.Items[lstEmployee.SelectedIndex] as NewsItem;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));



}



}

public class NewsItem
{
public string news_id { get; set; }
public string news_title { get; set; }
public string website_link { get; set; }
public string imagepath { get; set; }
public string news_date { get; set; }

public string image_path { get; set; }
public string news_detail_description { get; set; }

}


}



page1.xaml.cs



public Page1()
{
InitializeComponent();

Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page1_Loaded);


}

void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
NewsItem selectedNewsItem = (Application.Current as App).selectedNewsItem;
// TextBlockNewsDescription.Text = selectedNewsItem.news_detail_description;
string strURI= selectedNewsItem.news_detail_description;

// strURI.Replace("<link href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />", "");
// string k = "<html><body style='background-color:Black;font-size:30px;color:#fff;'>" + strURI + "</body></html>";



string k = "<html><body href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>" + strURI + "</body></html>";

webBrowser1.NavigateToString(k);


}




}
}
```

I want to apply page flip in page1.xaml i able to display data in mainpage.xaml in listview and in page1.xaml.cs i m displaying data in web view according to its item of main page now i want page1.xaml flip suppose user flip in next page then next  item detail showuld display in and if previous flip then it should display previous news detail. (Like android view pager )

i have to create news based application in windows Phone 7 please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the panorama template instead of the original template.

Comment: can i have ur email id so that i can send u My Proejct coz i did it But i want Page FLip in Second page if we flip next then it should dsiplay next item detail News .... if we flip Previous then it should display Previous item news i m displaying new detail In scond page in web view ok

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Pivot control to Page1.xaml, bind it against a collection of NewsItem and set the `currentItem` to the `selectedNewsItem`

Comment: Pivot control I have already used in Page1.xaml.cs and i m able to display in second page its HTML in web view But i want in second page flip view pager Previous next flip in detail page in second page

Comment: can i have ur email id Michael ?i can share mY project to U please so that u can do it Eaisly